# ArcMap Field Calculator gives ERROR 999999

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, error-999999

I am trying to do a fairly simple calculate but I keep getting ERROR 999999. I am running ArcMap 10.7.

My Input is:

```
(500,000/16) + ( (500,000/25) * [Join_Count])
```

[image: ma]

Comment: Add the code you use as text. Shouldnt `500,000` be `500.000` (or just `500`)?

Comment: No 500,000 is the value I'm seeking to use

Comment: That is probably not a valid decimal number (separator should be a dot, not comma). Use either 500000 (if it is five hundred thousand you mean) or 500 (five hundred)

Comment: That seems to be the issue, I removed the commas and it fixed the issue, thanks!

Comment: Why not just change (500000/16) to 31,250?

Answer (score 4):

Remove the commas and just enter:

```
(500000/16) + ( (500000/25) * [Join_Count])
```